# Input formats and WYSIWYG editor problem

Tags: 6, input-formats, wysiwyg

I have install 2 editor: YUI and TinyMCE

But wysiwyg settings are:

[image]

Why I can't setup editor on this input formats?

Comment: are you user 1?

Answer (score 2):

Check your permission page, and make sure you have the right permissions.  Also make sure there is no conflicting permissions

Answer (score 1):

you need to set this in the editor settings, not under input formats.  hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6 you need to go to admin/settings/wysiwyg to edit these.

[image: Example of what the WYSIWYG profile editor looks like in Drupal 6]

This image in front is a clean installation of Drupal 6 , viewing it as admin (user 1), and only having the WYSIWYG module and TimyMCE & YUI libraries installed.

You also need to have the user permission of 'administer filters'.  If your screen doesn't look like the example then maybe another module is causing a permission issue (another permission might be needed to be added) or something is corrupt.

Comment: did you solve your problem?